# When using the get_terms and trying to order the terms using the 'order' and/or 'orderby' does not work

Tags: terms

does this code really get you the categories in the order you want?

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'order=ASC' );
echo "<pre>";   
var_dump($categories);
```

for me, it does not. In fact, the following three produces the same output

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'order=ASC' );
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'order=DESC' );
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
```

Though the codex ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms ) says `order` and `orderby` valid params!

What am I missing? Does the below code really work for you and produce different outcomes?

```
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'order=ASC' );
echo "<pre>";   
var_dump($categories);
echo "</pre>";  
echo "<hr>";
$categories = get_terms( 'category', 'order=DESC' );
echo "<pre>";   
var_dump($categories);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: The code you posted at the end does return categories in different order as it should.

Comment: You are right. I tested it on on a fresh install and it does output the results properly. I think the theme that I'm using for the current site I'm working on has a filter that changes the default behaviour of this core API. I already asked the theme developer to see if they are involved with this. BTW, is there a way to see all the hooks and filters that the current theme is introducing?